# XLS multiple files convert to single csv in Linux

Tags: linux, csv, xls, converters

On a daily basis, I have received 20 .xls files in Linux box. Each file start from 6 row and convert into single.csv file. For example,

- .xls file 1 contains 106 rows
- .xls file 2 contains 206 rows
- .xls file 3 contains 56 rows

All three files data convert into a single CSV file. Single CSV file count should be 350.

I am using the command below to convert, but it is working one by one file not bulk mode.

```
unoconv -f csv -e FilterOptions="59,0,0,1"  test_amount1.xls  
unoconv -f csv -e FilterOptions="59,0,0,1"  test_amount2.xls  
unoconv -f csv -e FilterOptions="59,0,0,1"  test_amount3.xls
```

Can anyone let me know how to implement single shot all files conversion from .xls to .csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want but I assume you want to convert each xls file, then concatenate them all.

```
for input in test_amount*.xls; do
    unoconv -f csv -e FilterOptions="59,0,0,1" --stdout $input | tail -n +7
done >output.csv
```

Comment: just want to merge all three .xls data to single  .csv.

Comment: the above code is working for me but how to capture Input variable values into one .log file    $input

Comment: 1. please upvote the answer if it works. 2. I don't understand your last question, please spend more time in formulating clear use cases 3. if it's a new question (which I don't know) please ask it as as a new question, not as a comment